# facebook and twitter integration for ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am working on MPMediaplayerviewcontroller for video player in ios.. It is working fine..I am integrating Facebook and twitter for mediaplayerviewcontroller. After completion of  app launch  Facebook and twitter are not working..after coming from background to foreground it is working good..
This is my code.. plz help me any body. Thanks in advance…

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad

{

    mp = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];

    [mp.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];

    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mp];

    mp.view.frame = self.view.bounds; //Set the size

    self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    mp.moviePlayer.controlStyle =MPMovieControlStyleNone;

    mp.moviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;

    mp.moviePlayer.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    mp.moviePlayer.movieSourceType=MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(EnteredForeground) name:@"WillEnterForeGround" object:nil];

    mp.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];

    [mp.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];

    [mp.moviePlayer play];

    [self.view addSubview:mp.view];

    -(void)EnteredForeground

    {

        [self.view addSubview:mp.view];

        [[mp moviePlayer] play];

    }

    -(void)sharingAction

    {

        action=[[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle: nil destructiveButtonTitle: nil otherButtonTitles:@"Facebook",@"Twitter",@"Cancel", nil];

        [action showInView:self.mp.moviePlayer.view];

    }

    - (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex

    {

        switch(buttonIndex)

        {

            case 0:

                [self signInFb];

                break;

            case 1:

                [self signInTwitter];

                break;

            default:

                [self Cancel];

                break;

        }

    }

    -(void)signInFb

    {

        if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {

            controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

            SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler myBlock = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){

                if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled) {

                    alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"warning" message:@"Your post canceled" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

                    [alert show];

                }

                else if(oResponseData1!=nil)

                {

                    facebookSuccessAlert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"success" message:@"Your post succesfully send" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

                    [facebookSuccessAlert show];

                }

                [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];

            };

            controller.completionHandler =myBlock;

            [controller setInitialText:VideoUrlString];

            [controller addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"appIcon900x900.png"]];

            [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];

        }

        else{

            NSLog(@"UnAvailable");

        }


    }
```

Comment: Please Follow Stack Overflow Question help.Here Write Code in Right manner.

Comment: What is `oResponseData1`?

Comment: oResponseData1 means json response data

Comment: json response data of which request?

Comment: Why you are checking response of another request inside `SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler`?

Comment: if data is not available then i need to display error alert message so thats why i am writing like this